# Progress Bar Upload to S3 Django

Tags: python, jquery, django, amazon-s3

I would like to show an upload progress bar for S3 uploads from a Django site. Currently without the progress bar being manipulated by JQuery, the uploads are working direct to S3. Once I try to implement the progress bar using JQuery, the upload form still functions as far accepting input and the file, but will not communicate the file to S3.

Here is the upload view:

```py
from .forms import UploadForm

def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('upload')

    else:
        form = UploadForm()

    context = {
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, 'content/upload.html', context)
```

Here is the HTML:

```html
{% extends "about/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
{% block navbar %}{% endblock %}

<div class="site-section mb-5">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="form-register">
     <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         {% csrf_token %}
             <legend>Upload Content</legend>
             <div class="form-group">
               {{ form | crispy }}
            </div>
             <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Upload</button>
     </form>

     <div class="progress">
        <div id="progressBar" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">
           0%
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is the JQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('form').on('submit', function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);

        $.ajax({
            xhr : function() {
                var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

                xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {

                    if (e.lengthComputable) {

                        console.log('Bytes Loaded: ' + e.loaded);
                        console.log('Total Size: ' + e.total);
                        console.log('Percentage Uploaded: ' + (e.loaded / e.total))

                        var percent = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);

                        $('#progressBar').attr('aria-valuenow', percent).css('width', percent + '%').text(percent + '%');

                    }

                });

                return xhr;
            },
            type : 'POST',
            url : '/upload',
            data : formData,
            processData : false,
            contentType : false,
            success : function() {
                alert('File uploaded!');
            }
        });

    });

});
```

I assume there is something I need to change in the JQuery since I am overriding the default `submit` button action, but I am not sure what exactly to change in order to make sure the file goes to S3 via `django-storages` and `boto3`, the packages being used to communicate with S3.

Comment: Do you get any error? When you say the uploads work at first, are you also using ajax to post or just django?

Comment: were you able to find a solution? i am stuck in the very same situation.